# Is the author of a letter of recommendation notified that their letter has been submitted?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

My professor wants to give me a letter of recommendation for a graduate school that I am applying which I will submit via scanning. She didn't give offline recommendation to any One. So she wants to know, when I will submit the recommendation, will there be any email sent from the admission council to the professor informing a letter in her name has been submitted. It will be great if anyone here can inform me if there is any such process like this.

Comment: Normally when you submit your grad school application online, you provide the email addresses for your letter writers. Your letter writers then receive an email asking them to upload their letters of recommendation. Once they do so, they receive an email notifying them that their letter has been received.

Comment: What country is this?

Answer (score 1):

In recent years, my experience has been that, when I submit letters of recommendation via automated web systems (which is the most common situation), I get an automated confirmation. When I submit letters via individual emails, I sometimes get confirmations but usually not.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely receive a generic confirmation that your application has been received, which you can forward to the author of your LoR. If you want to be absolutely sure in advance, ask the institution that you are applying to. Practices differ, so we can't make a certain prediction.

Comment: In most of the universities that I am seeing there aren't mention of such mail, so I guess there aren't any such mail then considering they have put everything relevant in the reference option

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, the admission council will verify the recommendation by calling the professor. So one way or another your professor will know.

Comment: I think the question is about the real world.